# Store the hashed JWT token in the database

Tags: javascript

So for several days I have been struggling with this problem because I want to store my jwt token in the database.

The token looks like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiOWRiMTcwMmMtNDkyYy00MTJmLTkyM2QtM2Y5MWQyYzk0NTNjIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSX1JPTEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU0NzM4NTcsImV4cCI6MTYwNTQ3NzQ1N30.o9nEeH4V7PZ61jWRG7-7epH79Vi9HJQWorvx5A37q4o
```

And I would like to encode it with bcrypt, and then compare if the string is valid.

Unfortunately, the problem is that bcrypt only checks the first 72 characters, and my tokens here are very similar (only iat and exp are changed) and bcrypt doesn't work.

I want to store this token in the database as it is a token for refresh jwt.
Saving this in the database may exclude double logging of the same user (because when the user logs in, I create new refresh tokenn and save this token in the database)

I am looking for some alternative how to do this. I am using Node.js

Comment: [Does bcrypt have a maximum password length? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length)

Comment: bcrypt is not *"encoding"*, it's a hash. A specific hash designed for specific purposes, namely the hashing of a short-ish constant secret. What you have is not a short-ish constant secret, it's a long ephemeral token which is not supposed to contain secrets and which already includes a cryptographic  signature. It's unclear why you think bcrypt is the right tool for the job at all. If you want to store a hash of the token because you don't want to store the original but you want to deduplicate (?), then use a hash designed for that purpose, like SHA\*.